# .htaccess file with some exceptions

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a .htaccess file that follows these rules:

- all files (and subfolders/subfiles) of the folders images, css, js, admin, fonts should be reachable
- urls like bla.com/info should be redirected to bla.com/index.php?p=info
- urls like bla.com/products/22 should be redirected to bla.com/index.php?p=products&cat=22
- the url bla.com/products should be redirected to bla.com/index.php?p=products

Can anyone help me with this? This is what I got so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/

RewriteRule     ^favicon.ico           favicon.ico         [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?p=$1       [NC,L]
```

But it only works for the first 2 conditions...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 rules should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&cat=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This seems to work for the pages, but the images are rooted to bla.com/products/images/bla/bla.jpg on the products page

Comment: Ok that is common problem. You should use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: ok, changed everything to absolute urls and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(?:/(.*?)/?|)$ index.php?p=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```